# Where can I ask about building a drone hijacker like the Icarus box?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I read that one can build a device with off-the-shelf components that can hijack drones, similar to the [Icarus gadget](http://www.damngeeky.com/2016/10/27/45060/icarus-box-ultimate-drone-hijacker-can-end-drone-nuisance.html).

Where can I post a question that will help me build something like this?

Comment: Why so many downvotes??

Comment: Seeking help with dangerous and probably illegal activity, obviously.

Comment: That was published in tons of magazines, so I didn't know it was illegal.

Comment: The sensible thing would be to mention it, but hey, it's not as fun as downvoting the heck out of my question.

Comment: Two different comments have both mentioned it on the answer, and common sense should be telling you that if "hijack a flying object that is being legally used" is what you want to do, the law is going to disapprove.

Comment: @Nij Capturing the drone in your own home (and then giving it back to its owner, with a nice smile on your face ;-) ) is not illegal anywhere on the world. Anyways I strongly disagree the unfortunately common SE mentality that we want to play some "world police", it is not our task, simply thinking "it is maybe illegal", and voting the question down on this reason... well... maybe these voters should apply to a study on a law university, instead of playing an un-asked, cross-country criminal lawyer on the internet.

Comment: *"Maybe"* illegal? Interfering with communications, taking control of property and/or a vehicle by force, even disturbing the peace if you try to return it facetiously. Again: why are you still here when you obviously hate Stack Exchange so much? Nothing you say about your experience is positive, so just go, you're free.

Comment: @Nij, I didn't know it was illegal.

Comment: @Nij, I don't know where you're from, but recording everything I do at **my house**  with a drone is **ILLEGAL**.

Comment: Sitting on the street in a car filming that street, or biking around with a helmet-cam, are not illegal, whether or not your home is filmed, to the extent that the filming is reasonable; "I don't like it" is not a test of reasonability, and would not give you grounds to shoot out the tyres or knock the rider down and steal their bike in any case. Using unrelated illegal means to prevent a separate crime is called vigilantism, and authorities *strongly disapprove*.

Comment: I was sitting with my wife and my children on the porch of **MY HOUSE**  and the owner of the drone literally parked their drone twenty feet over me for at least five minutes. I'm surprised you're justifying this behavior.

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/17225/are-drone-intrusion-prevention-systems-drone-ips-systems-illegal and https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8407/autonomous-drone-over-private-property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a question on Electronics my first thought would be https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ but make sure that you read their [on-topic page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first, because I think your question will have too little detail to fly there.

Comment: Its also worth remembering interfering with Radio transmissions is illegal in many places and quite often these devices need a lot of skill and tuning to build.

Comment: It is worth noting that the asker appears to be asking about building something that would be considered illegal in practically every country. It is unlikely that *any* Stack Exchange site considers questions about how to perform an illegal action to be on topic.